# Windows 10 Left Control Key Not Registering

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I am on a 14" Razer Blade Laptop running Windows 10.
Some time after I installed VirtualBox, my left control key stopped working.

- Right Control Key Works
- I have uninstalled VirtualBox.  Issue Persists.
- Control+D results in D  (Same is true with Control+Any Key)
- When running the On Screen Keyboard (OSK.exe), pressing the Control key will light up the control key on the OSK.
- Filter Keys, Toggle Keys, Sticky Keys, Mouse Keys are all off
- I haven't spilled anything on the keyboard, usually the lid is closed.  I tried using compressed air.
- When I connect an external keyboard (MS Wireless) the same issue occurs.
- When I restart the computer in safe mode, the problem is still present

This issue has stumped me, and its super frustrating.  This is my development machine so I would rather not wipe it clean.

Comment: there is virtualbox data here that might apply somehow? http://askubuntu.com/questions/729342/why-does-ctrl-not-work-in-virtualbox-vms/729975  The first thing i was thinking because your OSK shows it working, would be those extra "pointer options" in the mouse pannel stuff , "show location of pointer" would be another test of the ctrl interactions.

Comment: Those articles are for when the control key is not working in the Guest OS - not in the Host OS.   Besides, I uninstalled VBox, do not have Guest Additions installed, and I even booted into Safe Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

It is not clear to me what *exactly* the problem was, but this is how it was resolved:

- Removed and reinstalled HID drivers.
- Installed Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center software.
- Installed all Windows Updates  (seemed to be a service patch missing)

Hopefully this helps someone else.